# Jetty default url not listing the project name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

This is the first time I am using a Google App Engine jetty server. I have deployed a webapp on jetty which was initially running on tomcat.

In tomcat the url pattern is localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.jsp

But in jetty it cuts out the ProjectName in the browser url, due to this the jsp in not able to read the resources

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I have remove to `${pageContext.request.ContextPath}` in order to run on GAE Jetty. Is there a way to fix this? I need to use the jsps as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `request.ContextPath` is the value of the `contextPath` that the webapp was deployed to.

If your webapp was deployed to a context path of `/` (root or default context path), then your `${pageContext.request.ContextPath}` is `""` per the spec.

See the javadoc for [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath())

Local GAE testing is usually on the `/` context path.

Also note that the typical deployment of your GAE webapp to `{appname}.appspot.com` would also be to the `/` context path.

Comment: So how do I change the context path of GAE so that it shows the app name in the url?

Comment: Google App Engine does not use and ignores context paths and context root configurations - [see the google appengine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#an_example)

Comment: So the only way left is remove the context path for js & css files from the jsp?